# Ionic Camera Border API

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, mobile

I'm building a mobile app in Ionic that captures text from a page. I want to show a guide/border like in the image below, so only the text within the guide is captured. I'm not sure if the Ionic API has this functionality. Maybe I need to switch to ios native.

Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Check This: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera-preview

Comment: These look like basic controls which i have working, the additional functionality i'm after is the 4 corner border/guide to allow me to drill down on a specific paragraph or sentence when capturing text from a page.